# Confused about generate-sources phase

Tags: maven, maven-3

From the Maven docs :

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

here is the description for 'generate-sources' : generate any source code for inclusion in compilation.

What source code needs to be generated ? All my source files are already created (by me) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about other projects like projects which use to create so kind of DSL via a grammar (ANTLR, JavaCC etc.), or you can think about annotated source code which will generate other things from it (like from Hibernate, JPA2 etc.) or if you think about WSDL which is the source to generate Java code from it etc. or about projects using XSD which generate also source code from it.

That's the reason having the generate-source life cycle phase.

Comment: ok, so a plugin will attach itself to the 'generate'sources' phase using <execution>

Comment: Usually yes, but there are some plugins do not do that in those cases you have to do that yourself which is not a big deal. This can be read in the plugin documentation. [Example here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/xjc-mojo.html].

Comment: thanks, FYI the link you posted contains a '[' at the end which makes it appear broken when clicked

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes, you already have all of the source files that you need. But that's not necessarily the case.

One simple example when you don't is when you use some web-service and you need to generate java code from WSDL. See [Apache Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/maven-plugins/maven-wsdl2code-plugin.html) or [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Some framework may help by generating boilerplate code. Then they should provide maven plugin that would have executing mapping to `generate-sources`.

Usually, and I think it s better, we don't need that as it make life a bit complicated.
Though R resource in Android may be good example.

Hint: to look at all phases, type `mvn anything`

[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "sdfsd". You must specify a valid lifecycle phas
e or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate,
initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resou
rces, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, gen
erate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes
, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-i
ntegration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy
, pre-clean, clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]